# How to get information about all types of data declared in a given package

Tags: oracle, oracle11gr2, plsql-package

Using the information from the representations of the data dictionary, get information about all types of data declared in a given package.

```
NAME            |   TYPE                |   PACKAGE
----------------------------------------------------
T_ASSOCIATIVE   |   ASSOCIATIVE ARRAY   |   MY_TYPES
T_TABLE_TYPE    |   NESTED TABLE        |   MY_TYPES
T_CURSOR_TYPE   |   EREFCURSOR          |
...
```

The program should be issued in the form of an anonymous block.

1)  `desc package_name;`

no variants to get certain rows, just parse: bad practive for such task

2)

```
select * from user_types;
select * from user_type_attrs;
select * from user_type_methods;
select * from user_procedures;
select * from user_source;
```

Doesn't get any result, only package type, but not types declared within this package

Comment: Why do you want an anonymous block?

Comment: Hi, Alex! It's the task from my university, I've spent 2 weeks to find out the right query, but have no results yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can see PL/SQL types in [the `all_plsql_types` view](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/refrn/ALL_PLSQL_TYPES.html)

```
SQL>  > desc all_plsql_types
 Name                                                              Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------------------------------- -------- --------------------------------------------
 OWNER                                                             NOT NULL VARCHAR2(128)
 TYPE_NAME                                                                  VARCHAR2(136)
 PACKAGE_NAME                                                      NOT NULL VARCHAR2(128)
 TYPE_OID                                                          NOT NULL RAW(16)
 TYPECODE                                                                   VARCHAR2(58)
 ATTRIBUTES                                                                 NUMBER
 CONTAINS_PLSQL                                                             VARCHAR2(3)
```

... or the `dba_` or `user_` versions if you prefer.

---

That view is only available from 12c. In 11gR2, if you [PL/Scope](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/adfns_plscope.htm) enabled, you can extract that information from [the `all_identifiers` view](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/statviews_1102.htm):

```
SQL> desc all_identifiers;

 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 OWNER                                     NOT NULL VARCHAR2(30)
 NAME                                               VARCHAR2(30)
 SIGNATURE                                          VARCHAR2(32)
 TYPE                                               VARCHAR2(18)
 OBJECT_NAME                               NOT NULL VARCHAR2(30)
 OBJECT_TYPE                                        VARCHAR2(13)
 USAGE                                              VARCHAR2(11)
 USAGE_ID                                           NUMBER
 LINE                                               NUMBER
 COL                                                NUMBER
 USAGE_CONTEXT_ID                                   NUMBER
```

... or the dba_ or user_ versions if you prefer.

Quick demo:

```
alter session set PLSCOPE_SETTINGS='IDENTIFIERS:ALL';

create package my_types as
  type T_ASSOCIATIVE is table of number index by pls_integer;
  type T_TABLE_TYPE is table of number;
  type T_CURSOR_TYPE is ref cursor;
end my_types;
/

select name, type
from user_identifiers
where object_name = 'MY_TYPES'
and usage = 'DECLARATION'
and type != 'PACKAGE'
order by name;

NAME                           TYPE              
------------------------------ ------------------
T_ASSOCIATIVE                  INDEX TABLE       
T_CURSOR_TYPE                  REFCURSOR         
T_TABLE_TYPE                   NESTED TABLE
```

You may need to recompile existing objects; either by recreating them or less intrusively with `alter package`:

```
alter session set PLSCOPE_SETTINGS='IDENTIFIERS:ALL';

alter package my_types compile;
```

Comment: ORA-04043: object user_plsql_types does not exist. Such error with dba_, all_

Comment: Hmm, what version of Oracle are you on then? I guess lower than 12c?

Comment: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production. It's at my university server.

Comment: Do you have [PL/Scope](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/adfns_plscope.htm) enabled? Can you see the information you need in [`all_identifiers`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/statviews_1102.htm) instead?

Comment: Yes, I can get needed info from `all identifiers`, but I've forget to mention, I also need to get info from packages created by me, and I can't get it from `all identifiers`.

Comment: Well, then use `user_identifiers`, or add a filter `where owner = user`.

Comment: SQL> select * from user_identifiers;

no rows selected

Comment: Sorry, why I can't get types of data declared to DBMS_* packages?(for instance, DBMS_OUTPUT)